# How to write an effective undo/redo mechanism for mongoDB documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that manages orders, and I want to be able to edit the order, and be able to "delete" an item but to be also able to undo this.

What I wanted to try is that for every item, I create a property called `isRemoved` as a boolean in the mongoDB document to be able to check if the item should be in the order at the end or not.

So my question is more about if in your opinion this is the most effective way to do it or is there a better way?

```
Order: {
   items: [
      {
         name: 'Cool Shirt',
         price: 13.0,
         isRemoved: true,
      },
      {
         name: 'Blue Tie',
         price: 10.0,
         isRemoved: false,
      },
   ]
}
```

I expect the item `isRemoved: true` after validations not to be on the order to be fulfilled, but in case the customer changes his mind, to be able to put it back, by changing: `isRemoved: false`.

Comment: I see only one problem which is you are expanding your data with useless information. If this parameter is going to change day by day then it is a status, but if it is going to be needed in one month it is good to keep those data into another document.

Comment: I don't think a "status" is appropriate in this case, since it means there's a broad range in values, and I don't need that. I just want to check if the item should be included in the order or not without deleting it from the document for future inspections and to be able to undo the removal from the order, and I don't understand what you mean by having the data in another document. @hurricane

Comment: So you are saving your data under Order schema. If someone deletes that data from Order schema, before your code delete it, save it to OrderDeleted schema.